# Parallelogram UILabel with top left edge rounded

Tags: ios, uilabel

Im trying to create an UILable with round edges more like a half parallelogram with corner radius (which says EU 15) as bellow. I already have an outlet to the UILabel. Any help would appreciate.

[image: wif]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a `UIBezierPath` as a mask for a custom view. You can then either add a label as a subview, or simply overlay a label on top of it.

Here is a basic example...

The red-ish rectangle just the view background - the white part is the custom view with path mask:

[image]

And here it is with a `UIImageView` behind it and a `UILabel` on top of it:

[image]

The code is pretty straight-forward:

```
@IBDesignable
class DanuShapeView: UIView {

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        // make sure the background is clear
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        // add the shape layer
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        // fill color for the shape
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        // make sure the background is clear
        backgroundColor = .clear

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let width = bounds.size.width
        let height = bounds.size.height

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

        // start at bottom-left
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: height))

        // add curve
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: height, y: 0.0),
                            controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: height * 0.6, y: height),
                            controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: height * 0.4, y: 0.0))

        // add line to top-right
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0.0))

        // add line to bottom-right
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))

        // close the path
        bezierPath.close()

        shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath

    }

}
```

Note that by using `@IBDesignable` you can see how it will look while laying out your views in IB / Storyboard.